# How to map from an array to multiple rows in the database with AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

On an ASP.NET CORE API implementation, let's say I have a simple business model like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {

    }

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public int[] UserValues { get; set; }
}
```

And I receive a JSON object like this:

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "userValues": [4, 5, 6]
}
```

My goal here is to save to the database a row for each `userValues` for that particular user, like this:

```
UserId | UserDbValues
-------+-------------
 1     | 4
 1     | 5
 1     | 6
-------+-------------
```

Would it be possible to achieve that using AutoMapper? Or do I need to manually loop and save each row?

I just getting familiar with AutoMapper, so this may be something really trivial or even impossible at all. I tried to map it this way but it didn't work:

```
CreateMap<MyClass, MyDtoClass>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.userDbValues, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.userValues));
```

Thanks a lot for any advice you may have!

Comment: It's probably easier to do and understand without involving AutoMapper for the expansion. This sounds like a job for the JSON deserializer. You could do an AutoMapper Custom Type Converter for `int` to your `User` type. And you might still end up looping to save records.

Comment: Share us the code you save `MyClass` to database. This it not related with AutoMapper which only convert `MyDtoClass` to `MyClass`. The key point is how you will insert `myClass`. in general, you need to loop `UserValues` to insert the `UserValue` table.